# How to calculate this derivative $D^{\alpha}f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a fixed vector, and $f$ a function given by $f(x)=\cos(x\bullet v)$, where $x\bullet y$ is the dot product.

What is the derivative $D^{\alpha}f(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and an arbitrary multi-index $\alpha$?

**-EDIT- I've made some progress:**

$D^{\alpha}\begin{equation}
   f(x) =
   \begin{cases}
     -\sin(x\bullet v)v^{\alpha} & \text{if } |\alpha |\mod 4=1 
\\ -\cos(x\bullet v)v^{\alpha} & \text{if } |\alpha |\mod 4=2
\\
+\sin(x\bullet v)v^{\alpha} & \text{if } |\alpha |\mod 4=3  \\
+\cos(x\bullet v)v^{\alpha} & \text{if } |\alpha |\mod 4=0
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}$

Is it correct?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you understand the definition of $D^\alpha$ for a multi-index $\alpha$?

Comment: @anomaly Unfortunately, I can't find information on this topic anywhere. No, I don't understand the definition.

Comment: In that case, you should have asked for an explanation of $D^\alpha$ rather than help for a specific problem. For a multi-index $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_k)$, we have $D^\alpha = D^{\alpha_1} \cdots D^{\alpha_k} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\alpha_1}} \cdots \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\alpha_k}},$ at least for $C^k$ functions, where the order of differentiation doesn't matter.

Comment: If a multi-index $\alpha$ is a vector, then what do you mean when you say $\alpha \equiv 4 mod 1$

Comment: @RogelioMolina I forgot to change that in the second part. Is it correct now?

Comment: @RogelioMolina I've made some changes. Could you review it please?

Comment: @Arthur: To make the notation simple, one usually writes $|\alpha| = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i$ and $v^\alpha = \prod_{i=1}^n v_i^{\alpha_i}$. You had it almost right. I have no idea where the $\alpha$ before the product sign comes from.

Comment: @user251257 The $\alpha$ before the product sign was a mistake. Is it correct now?

Comment: @Arthur: I think so.

Comment: @user251257: Ok, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f(x) = -y_i \sin(x\bullet y)$ and $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j \partial x_i} f(x) = -y_jy_i \cos(x\bullet y)$.

Comment: I've made some changes. Could you look at it please?